# How CPUs implement Instructions like MUL/MULT?

Tags: assembly, boolean, cpu, low-level, digital-logic

In different assembly languages MUL (x86)/MULT (mips) refer to multiplication. It is a black box for the programmer. I am interested in how actually a CPU accomplishes a multiplication regardless of the architecture. Lets say I have two 16-bit values in my registers and I am the cpu, so I have to implement MUL using the other bit-fiddling instructions I have (and,or,xor,not,shl,shr,etc). What shall I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_ALU on Wikipedia lists different methods for doing multiplication in a digital circuit.

When I worked on a project to add SIMD instructions to an DEC Alpha-like processor in Verilog back in college, we implemented a [Wallace tree multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_tree), the primary reason being it ran in a fixed number of cycles and was easy to pipeline.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370287/how-modern-x86-processors-actually-compute-multiplications/62117473#62117473), [Dadda multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier) are (nearly?) universally used in real life CPU ALUs, including modern x86.  Like Wallace multipliers, it can also be pipelined with fixed latency.

---

EDIT: You mentioned using the other bit fiddling instructions, on modern processors multiplication would not be microcoded like this; it'd be way to slow and the processor would get slaughtered in benchmarks.

Comment: I though cpus don't call their own instructions for efficiency reasons. I just had no other way to express myself, since the lowest level I have ever been so far is asm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes they do.  x86 is a complicated ISA and has some very strange instructions.  These instructions are translated into an internal micro-code program.  Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Intel_Nehalem_arch.svg, you'll see a complex decode unit and a micro-code sequencer, which does this

Comment: It's even worse than that on modern CPUs - given out-of-order execution, branch prediction, hyperthreading, etc, along with microcode, it's almost fair to say that the x86 ISA runs in a virtual machine that's implemented in microcode and circuits. But it's almost never necessary to worry about it...

Comment: @JeffShannon: `imul eax, ecx` decodes to a single uop on typical x86 CPUs as far back as Pentium Pro; there is a single fully-pipelined execution unit for scalar integer multiplies.  (On some AMD CPUs before Ryzen, it wasn't fully pipelined, e.g. Bulldozer-family can start one `imul` every other clock cycle.)  https://agner.org/optimize/.  SIMD integer / FP multipliers are also single uop for most vector multiply operations.  But Intel does microcode their integer division instructions.  There's still a hardware divider unit, but it takes multiple uops to do a `div`.

Comment: TL:DR: only complex instructions like `call` (branching and pushing a return address) decode to multiple uops, or crazy stuff like `rep movsb` (memcpy).  Frequently-used integer ALU instructions mostly decode to a single uop each. Out-of-order speculative execution doesn't change how the execution units are actually built; the OoO exec machinery exists to keep the execution units fed with work by finding ILP in a single thread. Yeah it's pretty different from an in-order pipeline, but whether you microcode a multiply or have dedicated HW is mostly independent of in-order vs. out-of-order exec.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://www.elo.utfsm.cl/~lsb/elo211/aplicaciones/katz/chapter5/chapter05.doc5.html) shows the logic gates for a 4 * 4 combinational multipler.  You can work up from there.

[Here is somebody's lab](http://www-unix.ecs.umass.edu/~smckenna/) where they describe building a 16 bit multiplier from 4 4 bit multipliers, each built with AND gates and full adders.  Full design, chip layout, and simulation waveforms.

Comment: both links are now dead :/

Comment: They are still available on the Wayback Machine.
https://web.archive.org/web/20091212185618/http://www-unix.ecs.umass.edu/~smckenna/
https://web.archive.org/web/20200216192105/http://www2.elo.utfsm.cl:80/~lsb/elo211/aplicaciones/katz/chapter5/chapter05.doc5.html