# What is the general purpose computer hardware for multiplication?

Tags: logic, hardware, cpu-architecture, alu

I am wondering what is the cost of multiplication operation in general purpose computers in terms of clock cycles. I mean what is the hardware or algorithm for multiplication. Is it Baugh-Wooley signed multiplication algorithm or Booth's algorithm or something else? Thanks for any information.

Comment: Search for "alu multiplication" (along with any other relevant designator). The specifics - and especially the 'clock cycles' - will vary by specific implementation as opposed to nebulous 'general purpose computer'.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370287/how-modern-x86-processors-actually-compute-multiplications/62117473#62117473 , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925143/x86-64-is-imul-faster-than-2x-shl-2x-add/37925245

Comment: For actually clock cycles, 3 cycles latency, fully pipelined at 1/clock throughput is common for integer multiply in modern x86; probably similar in other high-performance pipelines.  But check their vendor's manuals.  e.g. until Zen, AMD had slower performance for 64-bit multiply, vs. 32-bit integers.  Renat's first link answers for all ISAs, not just the x86 in the title: Dadda trees.